# Can we make raspberry Pi plug and play type

Tags: camera, shutdown

I am using raspberry Pi as a webcam server in my windows PC. It is working fine and I am able to use my raspberry Pi camera in Skype, Google meet etc but one thing that I want to improve is simultaneously stopping it or shutting down my Pi when I shut down my Windows PC. I even made a shell script and under Window Settings Scripts(Startup/Shutdown) I added the script inside shutdown but still it didnt work. Although strange thing is that, the command got executed as the below lines

```
this is in the first line
this is in the second line
```

got printed in a text file xy.txt inside this folder

> C:\WINDOWS\System32\GroupPolicy\Machine\Scripts\Shutdown

This is my script

```
@echo off
start "C:\Program Files\PuTTY" plink.exe -no-antispoof -ssh pi@192.168.1.30 -pw mypassword sudo shutdown now
(echo this is in the first line) > xy.txt
(echo this is in the second line) >> xy.txt
exit
```

Is there any other elegant way to get this done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that your script runs `exit` before establishing the connection to the Pi. Try

```
@echo off
start /wait "C:\Program Files\PuTTY" plink.exe -no-antispoof -ssh pi@192.168.1.30 -pw mypassword sudo shutdown now
(echo this is in the first line) > xy.txt
(echo this is in the second line) >> xy.txt
exit
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try this and let you know.

Comment: It worked after making those changes. Thanks.